# IReadBlock failed at Y offset : TIFFReadEncodedStrip() failed

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting the:

> band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset [number]: TIFFReadEncodedStrip() failed.

on all my TIFF raster files. I first thought it was perhaps my fault, because I've merged several land cover vector files into one, but I also have this error for a road raster (that I have cropped with my study area when it was a vector) which is from an official governmental GIS data catalogue.

I've read several forums on this error but I've yet identified what exactly is wrong (especially since I don't have any offset in X but only in Y, which kind of makes no sense to me) and even less how to fix it.

Can anyone enlighten me or redirect me to an article?

I use QGIS 3.28.4.

Comment: Happened to me when reading a TIFF parallelised with Python without read/write lock. Might help :)